# Qt SQLite can't perform Select querys

Tags: c++, database, qt, sqlite

I know many questions were asked around the issue I have, I spent along time trying to implement all kinds of solutions but didn't help.

I am trying to read a .db file using Qt SQLite platform. 
windows 8 Qt 5.3.2

Opening the db file in DB browser for SQLite and executing my simple query succeeds:

```
SELECT Name FROM Person ORDER BY Name
```

and there is a list of 10 rows at the output.

I would like to do it throw Qt. my code:

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
db.setDatabaseName("C:\mydb.db");
if(db.open())
{
    QSqlQuery qry(db);
    if(qry.exec("SELECT Name FROM Person ORDER BY Name"))
    {
        while(qry.next())
        {
           //some code
        }
    }

     QSqlError e;
     QString s,d;
     e = qry.lastError();
     s = e.databaseText();
     d = e.driverText();
}
```

this code falls, the `qry.exec` command returns false, and last error is **"no such table; person"**

Running the command:         `QStringList tables = db.tables(QSql::AllTables);`
after the Data Base is open shows that there is one table in Data Base called: sqlite_master.
trying to replace the query within the exec command with the query: `"SELECT tbl_name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table'"`
as says at: http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q7
causes the exec command to return true but `qry.next()` returns false already from the first iteration, although I have 5 tables in my data base.

I would be great full to how ever can me with my problem!

thanks!!!

Comment: I think you should use `C:\\mydb.db` instead of `C:\mydb.db`.

Comment: Thanks so much! I can't beleave it!!! I added and now it works :), I have some experience in Qt and used to double the slash but now didn't pay attention. Unbelievable that I spent a hole day about it!

Answer (score 1):

You should specify the path to the database file correctly. Instead of `C:\mydb.db` you should use `C:\\mydb.db` or `C:/mydb.db`.

That's because the compiler uses `\` as an escape character in strings (for things like `\t`, `\n` or `\r`). so `\\` is actually turned into `\`.